# bind future coming classes failed in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4yjohnz7/)

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
       $('p').addClass('red');


    });

    $('body').on('.red','click',function(){
        alert(''); // doesn't work?
    });
});
```

Why does the `red class`'s click event doesn't fire? I thought by using `on()` it will catch any future coming classes?

Is it because of closure problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect syntax for event delegation:

```
$('body').on('click','.red',function(){
    alert('test'); 
});
```

### Working Demo

Answer (score 0):

USe

```
 $('body').on('click','.red',function(){
        alert(''); // doesn't work?
    });
```

You misplaced class name and event..

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4yjohnz7/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Syntax error
$('body').on('click','.red',function(){
    alert(''); 
});
--OR--
$(document).on('click', '.red',function(){
    alert(''); 
 });
```